# Defining functions of a class in .cpp of a Dynamic-link Library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, header-files

Recently I started working with c++ and I was wondering.
If I'm working on DLL, I first define all the classes and and their functions in the header and then write their functionality in `.cpp` file in the same project.
But what if I instead defined only the classes themselves and then defined their functions in `.cpp` file.

It would somewhat reduce the amount of code required and the code would be more readable with much less `::` notations.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Are you saying you would want to put just `class C;` in the header, and then `void C::f() {...}` in the source? That won't work. Whoever includes that header would have no idea that the class provides a method named `f`, and so would be unable to call it.

Comment: Write the code for the program that uses the DLL and it is impossible to not get obvious.

Comment: You need [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329). **Badly!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your classes(structs, etc) and declare your namespace(s) and functions in your header.  That being said, you can use

`using namespace <your_library_namespace>;`

And then everything in your source file in `<your_library_namespace>` won't need to use `<your_library_namespace>::` before everything.

Comment: And by *"declare your class"* you obviously meant to say *"define your class"*. A class declaration is `class X;`.

Comment: Yes, you need to define your class(and structs, etc) and declare your functions